# Creating a Custom Tag To use if a input field is empty

Tags: java, jstl

I want to create a custom TLD Tag that assigns an asterisk beside the input field if the field is empty after the user submits.  What would be the best way to do this?  I am thinking of using  but can I do this all from the form, or should I go to the servlet and back?  I guess what I am getting at is what is the best way to do this?

### My Form

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="datetime" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
  <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Assignment 4</title>
<style type="text/css">@import url(/css/style.css);</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="registration">
<form action="registrationServlet" method="post">
<c:set var="customer" scope="session" value="${session.customer}" />
    First Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" value="${customer.getFirstName() }"/><br>
    Last Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" value="${customer.getLastName }"/><br>
    Email:<br>
        <input type="text" name="emailAddress" value="${customer.getEmailAddress }"/><br>
    Password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="password"/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br>
        Current Date/Time: <datetime:CurrentDateTime/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres a few possiblities for implementing this. The simplest might be to just do it in javascript.

You can intercept the form being submitted, check if the fields are empty and if they are, append the asterisk. If not, let the form be submitted.

e.g  add `onsubmit` to form

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="text" id="myinput">
```

...

Then using javascript and jquery :

```
function validateForm() {
    if ($('input:text').is(":empty")) {

        $('input:text').after("<span>*</span>");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The more robust way would be to implement server side validation aswell. If you're using spring mvc, theres loads of resources of how to do that.